# Add date to the path of old posts after migrating to another server?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, migrate

I had a page running at wordpress.com, and then I decided to move it to the godaddy's wordpress server (my knowledge on web platforms is very limited).
I have imported it and everything is working fine, except that, after the import, the date of the links of my posts was removed.
For example, before I had:

https://mundosemfim.com/2016/06/06/morays-o-incrivel-laboratorio-inca-pertinho-de-cusco/

now I have:

https://mundosemfim.com/morays-o-incrivel-laboratorio-inca-pertinho-de-cusco/

It screwed up with the google search, and also with my posts at my facebook's fanpage.

Is there any way to fix it? I don't have many posts, so it would be fine to edit each post if it was necessary.

Comment: Oh god, don't use godaddy, please... They have terrible support, and all around horrific hosting. I bought domain on namecheap and I'm happy with them. Don't know about hosting, but you can use Amazon AWS - I worked for several clients who had their WordPress installed on Amazon AWS and the sites are huge ( > 17000 posts), and work perfectly. Just an advice. I have only terrible experience with godaddy (especially when they put caching you cannot remove - terrible for development)...

Comment: Yeah, I've just found that out, unfortunatelly too late :(

Comment: Try asking for a refund? :\

Comment: @dingo_d While I totally agree about avoiding GoDaddy, you can do all your development locally to avoid caching, plus it's faster :)

Comment: Sure, that's correct. Doesn't negate the fact that the GoDaddy has crappy service...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your [permalink settings](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) have been changed.

In order to set them to date format, log in to your wp-admin, and click through to Settings -> Permalinks.

The option in there you want is the second one, marked *Day and name*.

Then click Save Changes, and reload your site to check if it has worked.

If it hasn't, you might need to:

- **Refresh your browser cache.** Usually closing and re-opening it should be enough to do this, but you might also want to go into your browser settings and clear the cached files (in Chrome, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> to open the dialog).
- **Check if you have any plugins running that could be modifying the permalinks.** SEO type plugins may do this; the easiest way to tell is to disable each plugin one-by-one to see when the Permalinks return to normal.
- **Wait for GoDaddy to clear their cache.** Unfortunately GoDaddy is known to be a bit lacking in some areas, and occasionally their servers can cache your website settings. Waiting an hour or so *might* help, but if in doubt, it can be a good idea to contact GoDaddy support.